# Need to generate custome url for bit.ly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bit.ly

Hi I am a web application in ROR and shortening url using bit.ly. whenever i create an url using bit.ly i could custom url like `http://bit.ly/19Mk8Oj` now i want to remove **bit.ly** and needs to add my own custom url like `ferdy.ly/sdf2323` how to do that?
when i Google about this and found the following url `http://support.bitly.com/knowledgebase/articles/76741-how-do-i-set-up-a-custom-short-domain-`. now i have a registered domain for this from **http://libyanspider.com/m** and need help to integrate the custom domain with my bitly account? and my application is a feedback engine wherein we are charging user for subscription so i choose business account and received a mail from bit.ly that per month i need to pay **$1995.**. is custom domain name in bit.ly will cost this much?

Comment: what you want is a url shortener algorithm you can google that if it would help

Comment: you can email sales@bitly.com or api@bitly.com if you have questions about integrating and the cost. you can connect the custom domain to Bitly even with a free account

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a url shortener algorithm.

Simple explanation with least efforts:

Have a table that you would store your URLs in for lookup, and the id should be auto-incremented(This is default with AR in Rails), convert the id to base 36 with ruby

`6788999.to_s(36) #=> "41ifb"` 
Then you can have a URL as:

`foo.com/41ifb`

When the request for the shortened URL hits the controller(which you can basically even use bare Routing for) convert the param to an integer:

`"41ifb".to_i(36) #=> 6788999`

This is a simple basic URL shortener service